# Spark SQL XML: How to access to the attributes in a tag

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark-sql

My xml-schema is as following:

```
root
 |-- generalinfo: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info-info: string (nullable = true)
 |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- files: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- parents: string (nullable = true)
 |-- participants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- signatures: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- size: string (nullable = true)
 |-- system-path: string (nullable = true)
 |-- satellite: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version_id: string (nullable = true)
```

I've read the XML file with the following code:

```
 df = sqlContext.read
.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
.option("rowTag", "product")
.option("attributePrefix", "_")
.load("datafiles/product.xml")
```

My problem is that all tags are empty.

Comment: If you want to just use "info-info" you can just do df.select("info-info").show and it will display the results !

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. The delivered dataframe is still empty.

Comment: CAn you share your XML so that i can try on my machine

Comment: @dstrbd : I added xml to original post please delete below as it is answer to the question.

Comment: please check [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760924/extracting-tag-attributes-from-xml-using-sparkxml )