# reading xml file with closed tag and many attributes in scala

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I am reading xml file in scala

```
<tag1>
  <tag2 id="0" attr1="abc" ... />
  ..
</tag1>
```

This was already reported as issue and closed .
https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/pull/303

However i am not able to resolve this.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.databricks.spark.xml._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, DoubleType,StringType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SaveMode}

object stack {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

    val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("id", DoubleType, nullable = true),
      StructField("attr1", StringType, nullable = true),
      ...
      ...
    ))  
    val df = spark.read
        .option("rowTag", "tag2")
        .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
        .schema(customSchema)
        .load("dummy.xml")

    import spark.sql
    import spark.implicits._

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp1")
    sql("SELECT * from temp1 limit 5").show()
  }
}
```

However `df.show(5)` displays no rows.

The resolution talks about using XmlInputFormat which i have not tried , if someone can guide then it will be helpful.

Similar type of solution works with nested xml file.

```xml
<books>
  <book> .. </book>
  <name> abc </name>
</books>
```

I want to see the dataframe with values to show. and later i want to read many xml files and join them in a sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mikhail for providing guidance however issue was very small. Sorry for not providing the actual xml file record earlier as the issue was in the attributes.

```
<users>
    <row Id="-1" Reputation="1" ..... />
</users>
```

The attributes were starting with caps, when i made them in small then this my solution started working(ofcourse i printed the schema before using it as suggested by Mikhail)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `_` prefix for attributes.

Data (dummy.xml):

```xml
<tag1>
    <tag2 id="0" attr1="abc"/>
    <tag2 id="1" attr1="abd" />
    <tag2 id="2" attr1="abd" />
</tag1>
```

Solution:

```scala
package main

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

object Main extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()

  val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("_id", DoubleType, nullable = true),
    StructField("_attr1", StringType, nullable = true)
  ))
  val df = spark.read
    .option("rowTag", "tag2")
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .schema(customSchema)
    .load("dummy.xml")
  import spark.sql

  df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp1")
  sql("SELECT * from temp1 limit 5").show()
}
```

Result:

```
+---+------+
|_id|_attr1|
+---+------+
|0.0|   abc|
|1.0|   abd|
|2.0|   abd|
+---+------+
```

How I got it:

1. Found that problem with scheme, because it work with children elements
2. Remove (or comment) custom schema (`// .schema(customSchema)`)
3. Print schema that spark is resolve (`df.printSchema()`)
4. Find what's you need
5. Create new schema

See also: [Extracting tag attributes from xml using sparkxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760924/extracting-tag-attributes-from-xml-using-sparkxml)

PS: Sorry for my English

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for the response. This seems a correct approach however still when i do printschema it shows nothing. i am running it like below: SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master local[*] --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.4.1 target/scala-2.11/stack_2.11-1.0.jar

Comment: @maks If you want, you can mark answer as "accepted". I'm don't understand why you need to use SPARK_HOME. I'm only use Intelij Community and click to run app, after adding libraries to build.sbt. Sorry for my English.

Comment: it is actually $SPARK_HOME to run spark-submit. I ran it in local installation on linux.